# Why did the Windows Team duplicated the "Program Files" folder to support x86 and x64?

Tags: windows, x86

A question that often puzzles me is why did the Windows team decided to duplicate the Program Files folder to support the 32-bit and 64-bit platforms? Doesn't this generate more work and mess for everyone in the long run?

What was the key factor that got them to duplicate the tree whereas some other system keeping a single "Program Files" directory (kind of like MAC's Universal binary format http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_binary)?

I'm sure there's a great reason which got them to create this "Program Files (x86)" folder, if anyone was in the room when this was decided, please share :)

Comment: This little thing called "backwards compatibility" was probably on their minds.

Comment: This question is off-topic. It is not a programming question and is not programming related. You are also asking us to peer into the minds of the windows design team - not something Stack Overflow users can currently do.

Comment: @Oded - "Not programming related"? Oh, come on, tell me you never crossed that kind of issue? :-)

Comment: @SimonMourier - The OP is asking for the design reasons. This is not on-topic.

Comment: Probably best asking this at [superuser](http://superuser.com)

Answer (score 2):

The c:\program files folder contains a lot of DLLs, particularly in the Common Files subdirectory.  The c:\program files (x86)\common files folder contains the 32-bit version of those DLLs.  Many of these DLLs have been around for a long time, almost two decades, lots of legacy programs depend on them.

Not virtualizing the folder would have greatly increased the odds for DLL Hell.  Also the reason that the environment has three variables that reference the Common Files folders, CommonProgramFiles, CommonProgramFiles(x86) and CommonProgramW6432.

Appcompat was pretty sacred at Microsoft, although it is disappearing.  Windows 8 is a pretty radical departure, this problem doesn't exist in Windows Store apps.